# C++ cpp socket and keyboard input interrupt

Tags: c++, event-handling

I have a cpp program that opens a socket to a bluetooth device.
Now I want to receive strings from the socket, and to send strings, received from the user, to the socket.
I want it all to happen simultaneously. Today I have an infinite loop that waits for data to come from the socket using recv(), but then I can't let the user give his input.
How can I make handlers for data coming from the socket and from the keyboard??
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should run your infinite loop in a separate thread. Then you can use your main thread to receive inputs from the user and send them to the socket.